# yajra laravel datatable return json table with rows that are in different sequence from the query builder output

Tags: laravel, datatable

I have a datatable with server side processing turn on.
Controller is able to perform a sort according to selected column.
When the collection is passed to yajra datatable, the order is jumbled up.
Attached below is code sample

```
$stocks = DB::select("Select stocks.id as id, stocks.name as name, stockprices.close as close from stocks,stockprices where stocks.id = stockprices.stock_id order by stocks.name asc");

foreach ($stocks as $stk){
            //perform some preprocessing to the name of the stocks...
           .....
}
// do a check before calling Datatables and sequence is correct.

$stockListDatatable = Datatables::of($stocks)
       ->setTotalRecords(count($stocks))          
       ->rawColumns(['name'])
       ->make(true);

return $stockListDatatable;   //check json content and the sequence is jumbled up.
```

System details

```
Operating System : Windows 10
PHP Version : 7.2.28
Laravel Version : 6
Laravel-Datatables Version : 9
```

Comment: dont use the order in DB query, but it's better use the order using the javascript.

Comment: thanks.i am using server side processing. i let Datatable handle it but it is not working properly and i use server side to do the ordering. It works but when i let Yajra datatable process to json, the ordering is jumbled up.